# TypeError: Unable to set property 'store' of undefined or null reference in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Below is the code I am using to get data from web API. But every time I try to retrieve      data I get same error: **Unable to set property 'store' of undefined or null reference in ember.js**.

```
/// <reference path="Lib/ember.js" />
/// <reference path="Lib/ember-data.js" />

var App = Ember.Application.create();

Ember.onerror = function(e) {

    alert(e);

};

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: App.ApplicationAdapter
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    ID: DS.attr("int"),
    Name: DS.attr('string'),
    Category: DS.attr('string'),
});



App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        {{debugger}}
        var store1 = this.get("store")

        var k = store1.find('product', 1)
        return k;
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of Ember.js do you use?

Comment: Shimon, I am using latest version of ember.js , ember-data.js

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the returned json from the server. You need to return the following object:

```
{
  product: {
    // key value
  }
}
```

If you want to use the DS.RESTAdapter defaults, you can just return the data in that format:

```
{
  product: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'some name',
    category: 'some category'
  }
}
```

And change your model mapping to:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

If you want to use the capitalized properties like `Name`, `Category`. You will need to override some methods of DS.RESTAdapter. If your endpoing doesn't match this format.

Other error is that doesn't exist a `DS.attr('int')` just `DS.attr('number')`. But you can remove the id mapping, since is created by default.

This is a jsfiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/W5LEH/

Comment: Thanks. I got the point my data format is not according to Ember.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that you are using last versions of Ember.js and Ember-Data.
2. This is how you define a store for you application:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: App.ApplicationAdapter
});
```

Note the capital `S` in `Store` and `extend` instead of `create`.

See [Ember-Data Guide](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html)